# Multiple inserts require that Id property is set?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

With Entity Framework 6.1.0 in combination with SQL Server 2008R2, I can't get multiple records of the same type inserted in a single Unit-of-work (without a hack), and I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong?

I'm working with Groups and Nations, where each Nation belongs to one Group, and a Group has a collection of Nations.
When I want to add 3 Nations to the same Group as follows:

```
using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext())
{
    List<Db.Group> groups = context.Groups.ToList();
    Db.Group groupH = groups.First(grp => grp.Name == "H");

    Db.Nation nation1 = new Db.Nation() { Code = "NA1", Name = "Nation 1" };
    //nation1.Id = 1001;
    nation1.Group = groupH;
    nation1.GroupId = groupH.Id;
    nation1.GroupOrdinal = 5;
    context.Nations.Add(nation1);
    Db.Nation nation2 = new Db.Nation() { Code = "NA2", Name = "Nation 2" };
    //nation2.Id = 1002;
    nation2.Group = groupH;
    nation2.GroupId = groupH.Id;
    nation2.GroupOrdinal = 6;
    context.Nations.Add(nation2);
    Db.Nation nation3 = new Db.Nation() { Code = "NA3", Name = "Nation 3" };
    //nation3.Id = 1003;
    nation3.Group = groupH;
    nation3.GroupId = groupH.Id;
    nation3.GroupOrdinal = 7;
    context.Nations.Add(nation3);

    groupH.Nations.Add(nation1);
    groupH.Nations.Add(nation2);
    groupH.Nations.Add(nation3);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

...I get an InvalidOperationException telling me: `The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.`

However, when I uncomment the 3 lines that assign each new Nation a primary key value (i.e. `nation1.Id = 1001`, etc.), the inserts work without a problem?

Note by the way that the column that corresponds with Nation.Id in the database is an Identity(1, 1) column, and that it uses this generated value to insert the new Nation rows with: it ignores the value that I assign them in code.
Entity Framework seems to require this value (without actually using it), which I think is weird. This shouldn't be necessary, right?

So, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit** I also created a simple "reference" project with just 2 entities that attempts to isolate the problem - and of course, this one *does* work :')
However, whenn I compared the contents of the ObjectStateManager (i.e. `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager`) between
the reference project and my real project, I noticed a difference in the contents of its `_entriesWithConceptualNulls` members:

- In my real project, each of the added Nations get added to the _entriesWithConceptualNulls collection, which apparently is the collection of entities
  that have a null foreign key value where they're not allowed to have one (see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/DataEntity/System/Data/Objects/ObjectStateManager.cs)).
- In my reference project, and also when I assign each new Nation an Id value, the `_entriesWithConceptualNulls` stays empty.

And even more surprisingly, in my real project, when I only insert only one Nation, it doesn't need to have an Id value either - `_entriesWithConceptualNulls` stays empty, and the insert just works.
Only when I insert 2 or 3 Nations an Id value becomes required...

**Edit 2** The problem probably *does* lie in the .edmx I'm using: when I have Visual Studio generate a new .edmx from scratch, the code works without having to set the Id's. To be continued...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. My project uses a slightly tweaked T4 template that lets each generated entity derive from a common `EntityBase` class. This base class also overrides `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, defining 2 entities to be equal when they return the same value for `GetType()` and *have the same `Id` value*.

Obviously, for the code in my question, this causes the 3 Nations to be considered the same by EF, thus resulting in an `InvalidOperationException`. When I explicitly assign each new Nation an Id, EF considers them as 3 distinct Nations and the inserts are performed as expected.

Because I don't want to require my new entity instances to have an Id, I've changed Equals() so that an Id of 0 counts as 'uninitialized': it never considers two entities with an Id of 0 to be equal. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just lose the `groupH.Nations.Add(nation1);` part (last 3 lines).

You usually do one of those things - when you set the nation's Group (from one side of the relationship) it's all set - doing it yet again from the Group's side seems to double that (I don't remember doing that recently, I'd expect EF to just handle that and don't report a duplicate, but seems it's not the case).

It's all part of the same relatinship  basically, just different sides of it, you don't need both.

Comment: I made the modifications as you suggested, but the results remain unchanged: it still needs the Id values for the inserts to succeed.

Comment: ok, that doesn't seem to be your main problem then - you need to post the full entities structure, keys etc. Normally you don't need to assign id-s to a primary key (if that's the nation's id), just let it auto-increment and don't touch it. You have something funny going on with the entities setup - you also don't need the `GroupId` lines, Group before that sets all it's needed, it shouldn't bother EF though.

Comment: Thanks for your responses so far, I've updated my post.

Comment: Like NSGaga stated, you dont need to do the connection twice. Have you tried doing it the other way around? Keeping the group.add and removing the groupId from nation? It shouldnt make any difference to your particular problem, but its just no point setting the connection twice;)